Why is the lock not working for a static variable in ASP.NET?
The function GetYYY() is called from an ASP.NET base page. So it can happen at the same time for several users. _data is something which should be initialized only once. However, the lock does not lock the static list. From our log, the log.Debug is executed twice and 2 values are logged (see the comment below). Why does the lock not work?
public class XXX
{        
    private static List<YYY> _data = new List<YYY>();

    public List<YYY> GetYYY()
    {           
        lock (_data)
        {
            if (_data.Count > 0)
            {
                return _data; 
            }

            _data = new List<YYY>();

            try
            {
                var query = @" SELECT ...";

                using (var dab = GetDataAccessBlock())
                {
                    OracleDataReader reader = dab.ExecuteSQLAsReader(query);

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        _data.Add(new YYY
                                      {
                                          P1 = reader["P1"].ToString(),
                                          P2 = ...
                                      });
                    }

                    log.Debug(_data.Count + " values are returned. this should be called only once when app restarts"); //this logs twice with wrong numbers 863 and 787... when there is only one user, it should be 432
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("..." );
            }

            return _data;
        }
    }
}


Because you create new object inside lock _data = new List<YYY>();?

better practice is maybe to have a private static object _dataLock = new Object(); and then do a lock(_dataLock) just to prevent having a single instance serving two purposes: holding  data and locking access.

@rene add a readonly there, too

A lock must be taken on an object that has a lifetime that outlasts the data over which you want to protect.
The lock you're taking on is on an object that is mutable within GetYYY() so has no guarantees, and is definitely a bug because of that. As expressed in the comments, lock on something else. Lock on something that is outside of the scope of that call, and persists across calls.
While not the best approach, you can still lock on the list, but only if you create it once, and change your semantics inside the call to clear the list before an add. In that way, your list persists across calls, but it's contents can be changed.
That said... better to use a class-scoped external lock as the mechanism.

the code is changed as you suggested and the errors did not show again. thanks!
